# How can we auto increment one of the columns of a compostite primary key?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, auto-increment

```
 CREATE TABLE abc(
        seq_id INT NOT NULL,
        name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        value VARCHAR(100),
        PRIMARY KEY (seq_id, name)
    );
```

The table contents would then be:

```
Seq_id    Name            Value

1        Bill.billNo     1234
1        Bill.date       25/07/2014
1        Person.fname     abc
1        Person.lname     xyz

2        Bill.billNo     1220
2        Bill.date       11/07/2014
2        Person.fname     def
2        Person.lname     ghy
```

i want seq_id column values to be auto incremented. how do i achieve that?

Answer (score 4):

This is not easy to do in general.  You can auto-increment an individual column (called `SERIAL` in Postgres), but not one column relative to another.  Well, you can.  But it requires the use of triggers.

In your case, though, I think you have a data modeling problem.  The `seq_id` actually represents *something*.  But you don't have a table for it.  I suspect that you should have a separate table, something like `BillPersons` with a `SERIAL` id with one row per sequence.  Then you would have another table, like `BillPersonDetails` with its own `SERIAL` id and a foreign key reference to `BillPersons`.

Comment: could u plz tell me how can i use triggers to implement  this? i have never used triggers before as i m new to this.

Comment: @SharmishthaKulkarni . . . My advice is to fix the data structure rather than trying to support a confusing data structure using triggers.